# call jsonp api from jquery nothing shown

Tags: jquery, instagram

I am trying call Instagram api to show the latest popular images, first i call the jQuery ajax function with the api url provided: when i key in the url in browser i will see the result of some xml files.
so i assume that is correct url,
but it will not work in my html file.
anyone knows whats wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=84abd0d71cb14ad9885cf1dc59594144",
         success:  function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $("#pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +
                "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url +"'></img></a>");
            }
    });

})

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="pics">

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

[edit: per a comment below, this advice is no longer current and the fiddle no longer working. Time permitting, I may find time to fix it; otherwise, just be aware]

You're just misplacing some braces. It happens. If you're not already using an IDE or other code-specific editor that can alert you about mismatched braces and tags, you should make the switch!

```
$(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: false,
        url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/popular?client_id=84abd0d71cb14ad9885cf1dc59594144",
        success: function(data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                $("#pics").append("<a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link + "'><img src='" + data.data[i].images.low_resolution.url + "'></img></a>");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KhW2E/

Also, you say that if you enter the URL, you see some XML. As you might expect from the name, what you're seeing is JSON. You're addressing it the right way, but it's helpful to use the right terminology to make sure people don't get confused.

Comment: Your answer helped me to solve an issue with the sparsely document JSONP in the instagram API: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ - replacing the URL for the  new version `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/nofilter/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN` works. Just considering maybe you feel like updating your post (also the jsfiddle does not work since the way to make API requests has been changed by instagram.

Answer (score 0):

Put the script after the `</body>` so that the ajax call finds the div.

Comment: Not necessary. It's already in a jQuery document ready function.